# Phalcon + Beanstalkd, how to link my controller?

Tags: php, phalcon, beanstalkd

I have a restful API powered by Phalcon that needs to background some tasks.

In a **MailController** I have a method that fetches mails from Imap. As I need to put here some slow stuff, I want to process it through a job.

My route calls a mailAction, the job is launched and the job should be executed in this controller.

**Services.php**

```
$di->setShared("queue", function(){
  $queue = new Beanstalk([
    "host" => "127.0.0.1",
    "port" => "11300"
    ]);

    return $queue;
});
```

*(Beanstalk service declaration in the di)*

**MailController.php**

```
public function fetchMailboxAction(){
    $queue = $this->di->getShared("queue"); 
    $idQueue = $queue->put([
      "readMailbox" => [
        "email" => $this->email,
        "customer_id" => $this->customer_id
      ]
    ],
    [
      "priority" => 250,
      "delay" => 10,
      "ttr" => 3600
    ]);

    /* other stuff, return blah blah */

}

public function readMailbox($params){
    // readMailboxStuff that should be executed through the job
}
```

**My question** : how do I specify to the job in which controller it Beanstalkd has to execute my function ? Documentation is quite evasive and I'm not sure I'm on the good way!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Beanstalkd is just queue for jobs. Not a job handler. You need to create some cron task to execute this function yourself. Best just to use cli tasks imho and collect queue jobs.

Comment: God... I thought Beanstalkd was meant to replace Cron tasks...

So what's the matter? Why don't use a database simple entry instead of beanstalkd? x)

Anyway thank you, I'm going to find how to create the perfect workflow using cron + beanstakld + supervisord + phalcon... So much stuff...

Comment: To no stress i/o and reduce read/write on hdd. Benstalkd works in-memory and it's much faster than putting it into database.

Comment: You hit a point! I will work on a working solution and probably post here, if somebody happens to the same issue :)